# I can cover you, and give you peace

Tags: riddle, word

Almost everyone owns me
I could die if not linked to something, but I can rise as well
I am loud for one, but quiet for the others
I can also cover you, and give you peace

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Headphones

Almost everyone owns me

> Almost everyone has a pair of headphones to listen to music.

I could die if not linked to something, but i can rise as well

> If not linked to some music player it does nothing, but if it does it plays music!

I am loud for one, but quiet for the others

> I am loud for who is having plugged to the ears but silent to everyone else.

I can also cover you, and give you peace

> Some types of headphones isolate you from the surroundings by blocking any other sounds from the outside

Comment: Congrats, you got it!

Answer (score 7):

> A mobile phone

Almost everyone own me

> [A lot of people have mobile phones](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Y2NsQ_I-vkc/UCYeUnNNHCI/AAAAAAAAAAs/et7r7ToIEYo/s1600/674px-Mobile_phone_subscribers_per_100_inhabitants_1997-2007_ITU.png)

I could die if not linked to something, but i can rise as well

> The battery runs out of you don't plug it in. Except for Nokia 3310. That runs forever.

I am loud for one, but quiet for the others

> some people have loud ringtones other have it on silent.

I can also cover you, and give you peace

> [Signal coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_signal)

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> **A Music System** or **A personal listening device** (Thanks Brent)

Almost everyone own me

> Everyone owns a music system in different forms.

I could die if not linked to something, but i can rise as well

> Music stops if not connected to power supply. Once connected, it starts again.

I am loud for one, but quiet for the others

> Its just a loud noise for the ones who hate music. But, the lovers enjoy it and don't treat as loud.

I can also cover you, and give you peace

> [Cover versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_version) of songs which is nothing but music, are infamous now a days. And nice music gives us peace.

Comment: Might work better if you specify personal listening devices...  Particularly, over-ear, noise-cancelling ones...

Comment: That's it, even if some points are wrong